# how to reference home folder on visual basic script

Tags: vbscript

Let me start by saying that I'm a linux guy and not really familiar with VBS or even windows global variables.

I'm being called upon to update a VBS script which basically copies the latest version of a access form to the computer.   Currently it puts this access form in C:\MedMaint.   The problem is that we do not run as administrators in this location. So when a new user tries to access the vbs script, the folder must be deleted by the original user.  I need to change this script to the linux equivalant of  ~/MedMaint, or "C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserName\Application Data\MedMaint"

Here is a sample of the code

```
    If Not FSO.FileExists("c:\MedMaint\" & File.Name) Then
        FSO.CopyFile File.Path, "c:\MedMaint\"          ' copy the missing file
    Else 
        Set RPFile = FSO.GetFile("c:\MedMaint\" & File.Name)    ' Get the file object from the local object
        If (File.DateLastModified >= RPFile.DateLastModified) Then
            FSO.CopyFile File.Path, "c:\MedMaint\"
```

I would like to know how to change the c:\MedMaint\ reference to the user's home dir

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the path of the **user's profile folder** (e.g. *C:\Documents and Settings\<username>* in Windows XP or *C:\Users\<username>* in Windows Vista), you can do any of the following:

- Evaluate the `USERPROFILE` environment variable using the [`WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf.aspx) method:

  ```
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
  ```
- Retrieve the folder path using the [`Shell.Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774085.aspx) method:

  ```
  Const ssfPROFILE = &H28
  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  strHomeFolder = oShell.NameSpace(ssfPROFILE).Self.Path
  ```

If you need the path of the **application data folder** (e.g. *C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data* in Windows XP or *C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming* in Windows Vista), you can use similar code:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")

''# or

Const ssfAPPDATA = &H1A
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
strHomeFolder = oShell.NameSpace(ssfAPPDATA).Self.Path
```

To append a folder name to a path, you could simply use string concatenation like this:

```
strMedMaintFolder = strHomeFolder & "\MedMaint"
```

Alernatively, if your script contains many path concatenations, I suggest using the [`FileSystemObject.BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) method, because it takes care of path separators (`\`) for you:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strMedMaintFolder = fso.BuildPath(strHomeFolder, "MedMaint")
```

Comment: thank you  this was what I needed.... " Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%") "

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Shell Object.

Have a look at [this](http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/vbscript_display_special_folder_locations.aspx) link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it if you are using the Windows Scripting Host.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
```